# Comparing string with file

Tags: php

I want to add string text (ip adress) in end of file if not exist.
I have a database with IP Adress, I want to add ip if not exist in my text file.

```
$rows=mysql_num_rows($resultcheck);
$fields=mysql_num_fields($resultcheck);

for ($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++){
  for($j=0;$j<$fields;$j++){
    //echo '<b>Date : </b>'.date("Y-m-d").' IP : ';
    //echo long2ip(mysql_result($resultcheck,$i,$j)).'<br>';
    $file=fopen("ff.txt","a+");
    fputs($file,long2ip(mysql_result($resultcheck,$i,$j)).":");
    $line=file('ff.txt');
    foreach($line as $line){
      $arr=explode(':',$line);
      if ($arr[0] != long2ip(mysql_result($resultcheck,$i,$j))){
        fputs($file,long2ip(mysql_result($resultcheck,$i,$j)).":");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to add it in a file or a database? Or are you using file as a database?

Comment: i want to add in a file

Comment: Your question has already been answered then.

Comment: see my code , i have false result

Answer (score 0):

For add strings to end of file open file with flag "a"

For compare string - you can open file with function file. It return array of lines in file. For find similar string just use foreach by this array from file.

In other words - show your code

Answer (score 0):

Read line by line from file

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $buffer;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Append to file

```
<?php
$file = 'people.txt';
// The new person to add to the file
$person = "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents to the file, 
// using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
// and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```